# Bootstrapped Prediction Interval for Adaptive Lasso

Tags: r, bootstrap, lasso, prediction-interval, glmnet

I am attempting to calculate a 95% prediction interval from an adaptive lasso model using the `glmnet::` package in R.  I adapted my method from the Python code in [this blog post](https://www.saattrupdan.com/2020-03-01-bootstrap-prediction). Essentially it boils down to bootstrapping the training data, and then getting a distribution of model variance, model bias, and sampling error, adding those error sources together, and then finding the 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles of the that final distribution.  What is perplexing to me is why the bootstrapped prediction interval from adaptive lasso is so much wider than an analogous prediction interval from an OLS model on the same data in the artificial example below.  At first, I thought this might be a result of the bias introduced through Lasso, but that should come with a concomitant reduction in variance.  Additionally, the final model with adaptive lasso is much closer to the true data generating mechanism than the final OLS model.  Finally, plotting the observed vs. predicted values from the prediction data set shows that almost all of the data are within the 95% prediction interval of the OLS (as expected).  Am I including too many sources of error or miscalculating them?  Note, I have tried increasing the number of bootstrap iterations, not setting a fixed lasso tuning parameter (i.e., lambda), and yet I get essentially the same results.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##
if(!require(glmnet)){
install.packages("glmnet")
}

## Bootstrapped Prediction Interval Function ##
pred_interval<-function(x0, x_train, y_train, lambda, w, alpha=1, alpha_thresh = 0.05){
  require(glmnet)
  n <- nrow(x_train)
  b <- 50
  
  val_resids<-NULL
  bootstrap_preds<-NULL
  for (i in 1:b){
    N<-c(1:n)
    train_ids <- sample(N, n, replace=TRUE)
    val_ids <- N[-train_ids]
    alasso <- glmnet(x_train[train_ids,], y_train[train_ids], alpha=alpha, lambda=lambda penalty.factor=w)
    preds <- predict(alasso, x_train[val_ids,])
    val_resids[[i]] <- y_train[val_ids] - preds
    bootstrap_preds[[i]] <- predict(alasso, x0)
  }
  
bootstrap_preds <- do.call(rbind, bootstrap_preds)
bootstrap_preds1 <- bootstrap_preds - mean(bootstrap_preds)
val_resids <-do.call(rbind, val_resids)

alasso<-glmnet(x_train, y_train)
preds<-predict(alasso, x_train)
train_resids<-y_train - preds

val_resids<-quantile(val_resids, seq(0,1,0.01))
train_resids<-quantile(train_resids, seq(0,1,0.01))


no_info_error <- mean(abs(sample(y_train, n, replace=FALSE)/sample(preds, n, replace=FALSE)))
generalization <- abs(mean(val_resids) - mean(train_resids))
no_info_val <- abs(no_info_error - train_resids)
rel_overfit<-mean(generalization/no_info_val)
weight <- .632 /(1-.368 * rel_overfit)
residual <- (1 - weight)*train_resids + weight*val_resids

k <- 1
C <- NULL
for (m in 1:length(bootstrap_preds1)){
  for(o in 1:length(residual)){
    C[k]<-bootstrap_preds1[m]+residual[o]
    k<-k+1
  }
}

qs <- c(alpha_thresh / 2,  (1 - alpha_thresh / 2))
pred_qs<-quantile(C, qs)+mean(bootstrap_preds)
return(cbind(mean(bootstrap_preds),pred_qs))
}

##Fake Training Data##
set.seed(63)#For Reproducibility

x1<-runif(100, 30, 50)
x2<-runif(100, 23, 150)
x3<-runif(100, 400, 1500)
x4<-runif(100, 56, 123)
x5<-runif(100, 3, 12)
e<-rnorm(100, 10, 5) #

Y<-15.3+2.1*x1 + 6.3*x2 + 1.5*x4 +e
X<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
dtf<-data.frame(cbind(Y,X))

##Running Adaptive Lasso to get tuning parameter values##
mod.full<-lm(Y~., data=dtf)
w<-1/abs(matrix(mod.full$coefficients[-c(1)]))
alss<-cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(X), y=Y, alpha=1, family="gaussian", penalty.factor=w)

##Fake Prediction Data##
set.seed(12)#To get a reproducible new dataset

x1<-runif(100, 30, 50)
x2<-runif(100, 23, 150)
x3<-runif(100, 400, 1500)
x4<-runif(100, 56, 123)
x5<-runif(100, 3, 12)

x0<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)

##Calculating Bootstrapped Prediction interval using Adaptive Lasso##
out<-apply(x0, 1, pred_interval, x_train=as.matrix(X), y_train=Y, w=w, lambda=min(alss$lambda))

useit<-t(out)
testit<-15.3+2.1*x0[,1] + 6.3*x0[,2] + 1.5*x0[,4] +e

##Calculating prediction interval from OLS##
detm<-predict(mod.full, x0, level=0.95,interval="prediction")

##Plotting Results##
plot(useit[,2], testit)
points(useit[,3], testit, col="red") #Bootstrapped Lower Bound
points(useit[,4], testit, col="red") #Bootstrapped Upper Bound
points(detm[,2], testit, col="blue") #OLS Lower Bound
points(detm[,3], testit, col="blue") #OLS Upper Bound
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out just to be an oversight in my code.  When calculating fitting the adaptive lasso model to my training data set in the prediction interval function, I forgot to pass the tuning parameters for the coefficient penalties and the lambda value to `glmnet().`  As soon as I included those tuning parameters, I got the same results as OLS.  Here is the corrected code:

````
##Loading Necessary Packages##
if(!require(glmnet)){
install.packages("glmnet")
}

## Bootstrapped Prediction Interval Function ##
pred_interval<-function(x0, x_train, y_train, lambda, w, alpha=1, alpha_thresh = 0.05){
  require(glmnet)
  n <- nrow(x_train)
  b <- 50
  
  val_resids<-NULL
  bootstrap_preds<-NULL
  for (i in 1:b){
    N<-c(1:n)
    train_ids <- sample(N, n, replace=TRUE)
    val_ids <- N[-train_ids]
    alasso <- glmnet(x_train[train_ids,], y_train[train_ids], alpha=alpha, lambda=lambda penalty.factor=w)
    preds <- predict(alasso, x_train[val_ids,])
    val_resids[[i]] <- y_train[val_ids] - preds
    bootstrap_preds[[i]] <- predict(alasso, x0)
  }
  
bootstrap_preds <- do.call(rbind, bootstrap_preds)
bootstrap_preds1 <- bootstrap_preds - mean(bootstrap_preds)
val_resids <-do.call(rbind, val_resids)

alasso<-glmnet(x_train, y_train, alpha=alpha, lambda=lambda, penalty.factor=w)
preds<-predict(alasso, x_train)
train_resids<-y_train - preds

val_resids<-quantile(val_resids, seq(0,1,0.01))
train_resids<-quantile(train_resids, seq(0,1,0.01))


no_info_error <- mean(abs(sample(y_train, n, replace=FALSE)/sample(preds, n, replace=FALSE)))
generalization <- abs(mean(val_resids) - mean(train_resids))
no_info_val <- abs(no_info_error - train_resids)
rel_overfit<-mean(generalization/no_info_val)
weight <- .632 /(1-.368 * rel_overfit)
residual <- (1 - weight)*train_resids + weight*val_resids

k <- 1
C <- NULL
for (m in 1:length(bootstrap_preds1)){
  for(o in 1:length(residual)){
    C[k]<-bootstrap_preds1[m]+residual[o]
    k<-k+1
  }
}

qs <- c(alpha_thresh / 2,  (1 - alpha_thresh / 2))
pred_qs<-quantile(C, qs)+mean(bootstrap_preds)
return(cbind(mean(bootstrap_preds),pred_qs))
}

##Fake Training Data##
set.seed(63)#For Reproducibility

x1<-runif(100, 30, 50)
x2<-runif(100, 23, 150)
x3<-runif(100, 400, 1500)
x4<-runif(100, 56, 123)
x5<-runif(100, 3, 12)
e<-rnorm(100, 10, 5) #

Y<-15.3+2.1*x1 + 6.3*x2 + 1.5*x4 +e
X<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
dtf<-data.frame(cbind(Y,X))

##Running Adaptive Lasso to get tuning parameter values##
mod.full<-lm(Y~., data=dtf)
w<-1/abs(matrix(mod.full$coefficients[-c(1)]))
alss<-cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(X), y=Y, alpha=1, family="gaussian", penalty.factor=w)

##Fake Prediction Data##
set.seed(12)#To get a reproducible new dataset

x1<-runif(100, 30, 50)
x2<-runif(100, 23, 150)
x3<-runif(100, 400, 1500)
x4<-runif(100, 56, 123)
x5<-runif(100, 3, 12)

x0<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)

##Calculating Bootstrapped Prediction interval using Adaptive Lasso##
out<-apply(x0, 1, pred_interval, x_train=as.matrix(X), y_train=Y, w=w, lambda=min(alss$lambda))

useit<-t(out)
testit<-15.3+2.1*x0[,1] + 6.3*x0[,2] + 1.5*x0[,4] +e

##Calculating prediction interval from OLS##
detm<-predict(mod.full, x0, level=0.95,interval="prediction")

##Plotting Results##
plot(useit[,2], testit)
points(useit[,3], testit, col="red") #Bootstrapped Lower Bound
points(useit[,4], testit, col="red") #Bootstrapped Upper Bound
points(detm[,2], testit, col="blue") #OLS Lower Bound
points(detm[,3], testit, col="blue") #OLS Upper Bound
```
````